# Expression of type 'System.Func`2[T,System.Boolean]' cannot be used for return type 'System.Boolean'

Tags: c#, lambda

I have an issue with converting my *Expression* into `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`. Is this possible?

The Expression.Lambda call is erroring with `` Expression of type 'System.Func`2[T,System.Boolean]' cannot be used for return type 'System.Boolean' `` and that doesn't make sense to me as I thought by the definition the function has the matching return type.

```
Expression expression = serializer.DeserializeText(serializedText);
ParameterExpression entityType = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
Expression<Func<T, bool>> typedExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(expression, entityType);
```

The expression is a strong typed lambda, e.g., s => idArray.Contains(s.SomeIntColumn) where s is type T. The expression is then serialised using a LINQ serializer and then deserialized into a System.Linq.Expression. Since I know it is a function of type T with return bool, I want to strongly type that.

Comment: What type `expression` is?

Comment: what is `serializer.DeserializeText(serializedText)` here? it is hard to comment without the full context, but note that it isn't using the lambda parameter at all

Comment: So is expression already a `LambdaExpression`?

Comment: Please see edits. Yes it is a lambda expression. Before serialization, it was Expression<Func<T, bool>>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what the `serializedText` is in your snippet, but as long as it is a `LambdaExpression` which returns a `boolean` you should be able to do the below.

```
  Expression expression = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Constant(true), Expression.Parameter(typeof(string)));

  Expression<Func<string, bool>> typedExpression = (Expression<Func<string, bool>>)(expression);
        
  Console.WriteLine(typedExpression.Compile().Invoke("Hello"));
```

Replace `string` with your generic type.

In your example, if the `serializedText` can be deserialized into a `Expression` the below should work. You would have to change it for your considerations.

```
Expression<Func<T, bool>> typedExpression = (Expression<Func<T, bool>>)Expression.Lambda(
                                                                        serializer.DeserializeText(serializedText), 
                                                                        Expression.Parameter(typeof(T)));
```

Comment: This depends. If the OP is constructing lambda from another lambda, sometimes the parameters need to be updated. Like `o.Method()` needs to be updated to `x => x.Method()`.